# Trying to identify zombie movie from 80's or 90's

Tags: story-identification, movie, zombie

I'm trying to find the title of a movie from the 1980's or early 1990's that released in the US. It was a serious movie with more of an action vibe than straight horror - very Resident Evil-ish.

In the film, a facility of some kind - located outside a small town - goes into lockdown mode after a contagion gets released. As the government surrounds the facility and contemplates how to kill the contagion, the local sheriff sneaks into the facility in order to rescue his girlfriend or wife, who was an employee in the facility when it locked down. The contagion has turned everyone inside into zombie-like creatures, but the sheriff finds the girlfriend unaffected despite many close encounters with the zombies. In the end, it turns out that she's unaffected because

> she's pregnant, and the hormones produced by her body render her immune.

Does this ring a bell with anyone?

**Further Info:** The sheriff was a Caucasian man in his late 30's or 40's with short dark hair - kind of a rugged looking guy. The girlfriend/wife was a Caucasian woman in her 30's or so with a short tomboy-ish haircut and dark hair. I could be wrong but I think the GF was a security officer at the facility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Warning Sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warning_Sign_(film))*, 1985, Sam Waterston, Kathleen Quinlan

[image]

> The movie tells about the outbreak of a virulent bacteria in a secret military laboratory operating under the guise of a pesticide manufacturer. During routine work a sealed tube is broken, releasing the secret biological weapon. Where upon detecting the release of the agent, one of the plant's security officers activate "Protocol One," a procedure sealing all of the workers inside from the outside world and they are left to wait out the deadly effects. A local County Sheriff whose pregnant wife, the security officer, is trapped inside, and with the help of a past employee who is a known alcoholic, must fight through a government agency and the chemically affected workers to find his wife and put a stop to the spread of the lethal weapon. The former employee had started creating an antidote to the weapon, which the sheriff and his wife create and deploy.

It has a locked-down facility outside a small town and a sheriff trying to rescue his pregnant wife.

Here's the trailer:

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. Your answer would benefit from some elaboration on why you think this movie is what OP is looking for.

Comment: This does indeed sound like what I'm looking for. Sam Waterston appears to ring a bell, although he was obviously much younger than. Flesh this answer out some with a summary or matching points or something, and I'll accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, I'll give more detail in the future!